# migrations for djstripe subscription payment api integration not working

Tags: python, django

bellow error i am facing while running this command `python3 manage.py djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe`

**Error:**

```
     djstripe.UsageRecord.livemode: (fields.W903) NullBooleanField is deprecated. Support for 
     it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0.
     HINT: Use BooleanField(null=True) instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is fixed in DJ-Stripe 2.4.0 https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/issues/1265